# How to fix "403 - Forbidden: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied"

Tags: laravel, apache, redhat

I just deployed my Laravel project into my Azure VM, which runs on Redhat, Linux. Everything is fine until i try to upload an image which is over 1MB in terms of size. When i do that and click on submit, I always get this error:

`403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.`

What and where would the issue be? Error logs in apache are clean. And my php.ini has already been configured to allow 100M for max_upload and so on. The tricky part is that this only applies to images, whereas when i try to upload a pdf for example that has a size of 5MB, it uploads just fine.

Comment: Do you have a php error log, besides of the apache log?

Comment: cant find it. haven't gotten any php errors at all :/

Comment: or more like, found it, but the only "errors" were of me shutting down and restarting httpd.